Space of linear operators has a basis consisting of diagonalizable operators (Linear Algebra Done Right, Axler Section 5D Q17)
Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional. Prove that $\mathcal{L}(V)$ has a basis consisting of diagonalizable operators.
This problem is taken from Linear Algebra Done Right by Axler, Section 5D, Exercise 17.
I can show that matrices of the form
$$
T_{i, j} = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } (i, j) \in \{(a, b), (b, a)\},\\
0  & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
$$
are diagonalizable, and there are $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ such matrices. However, I can't figure out what other basis elements need to be included.
Skew symmetric matrices like the following are not diagonalizable over the reals, but otherwise the addition of those matrices would complete the problem.
$$
T_{i, j} = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } (i, j) = (a, b),\\
-1 & \text{if } (i, j) = (b, a),\\
0  & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
$$

How about $$ T_{i,j} = \cases{1 & if $(i,j) = (a,b)$\cr
                              2 & if $(i,j) = (b,a)$\cr
                              0 & otherwise} $$

Suppose $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over a a field $\mathbb F$. We may identify $\mathcal{L}(V)$ with $M_n(\mathbb F)$, the set of all $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb F$. Denote by $E_{ij}$ the matrix with a $1$ at the $(i,j)$-th position and zero elsewhere. Clearly, $\{E_{ii}:1\le i\le n\}\cup\{E_{ij}:i\ne j\}$ form a basis of $M_n(\mathbb F)$, but $E_{ij}$ is not diagonalisable when $i\ne j$ (because it is nilpotent and nonzero). To fix this, modify the basis to
$$
\{E_{ii}:1\le i\le n\}
\cup\{E_{ii}+E_{ij}:i\ne j\}.
$$
This works for any field $\mathbb F$.

How do we know the modified basis is still diagonalizable? It's not obvious to me what the minimal polynomial of the modified off-diagonal elements is.

@GaryPinise $E_{ii}$ is already a diagonal matrix. When $i\ne j$, $E_{ii}+E_{ij}$ is diagonalisable because it is similar to $E_{ii}$. More specifically, $P^{-1}\big(E_{ii}+E_{ij}\big)P=E_{ii}$ when $P=I-E_{ij}$ (note that $P^{-1}=I+E_{ij}$ exists in any field $\mathbb F$).
